# solve $\int \frac{dx}{3+\sqrt{x+2}}$

Tags: integration

> $$\int \frac{dx}{3+\sqrt{x+2}}$$

How should I approach this? U-substituion does not seem to work

Comment: What substitution did you attempt? There's one that leads to an efficient solution.

Comment: a change of variable $u = 3+\sqrt{x+2}$ may make it easier.

Answer (score 3):

Let $u=3+\sqrt{x+2}$

$du=\frac 1{2\sqrt{x+2}}dx$

$$\int \frac{2(u-3)}{u}du$$

Comment: it doesn't get any faster! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=x+2$, then
$$I=\int\frac{du}{3+\sqrt{u}}$$

Let $v=\sqrt{u}$, then
$$I=\int\frac{2vdv}{3+v}$$

Let $w=3+v$, then
$$I=\int\frac{2(w-3)}{w}dw=\int2dw-\int\frac{6}{w}dw=2w-6\ln|w|+C$$
$$=2(3+\sqrt{x+2})-6\ln|3+\sqrt{x+2}|+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y = x + 2, dy = dx$.
$$ \int \frac{dx}{3+\sqrt{x+2}} = \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{y} + 3}
$$
Let $z = \sqrt{y}, dz = dy/(2\sqrt{y})$.
$$ \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{y} + 3} = \int \frac{2\sqrt{y} dz}{z+3} = 2\int \frac{z}{z+3} dz
$$
Then do partial fraction decomposition.